# do calculation inside JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a simple issue but cannot solve it as I am not very good at algorithm!
I have an JSONArray in this form:

```
[{"values":[{"time":1434976493,"value":"50"},
{"time":1434976494,"value":"100"}],"counter":"counter1"},

{"values":[{"time":1434976493,"value":"200"},
{"time":1434976494,"value":"300"}],"counter":"counter2"},

{"values":[{"time":1434976493,"value":"400"},   
{"time":1434976494,"value":"600"}],"counter":"total"}]
```

What I want to do is to get the integer value for counter 1 and counter 2 and then divide them by total counter and put them in a list or array. and of course I want total counter to be untouched! So the calculation would be `Counter1.value/total.value`, `Counter2.value/total.value` So for example the counter 1 would be like this:

```
{"values":[{"time":1434976493,"value":"50/400"},{"time":1434976494,"value":"100/600"}],"counter":"counter1"}
```

Thats an uncompleted attempt :

(given that I have list of counters that I can iterate:)

```
int index= counters.indexOf("total");
JSONObject rec = array.getJSONObject(index);
```

and then I got this for total counter:

```
{"values":[{"time":1434976493,"value":"400"},   
    {"time":1434976494,"value":"600"}]
```

not sure what is the next step?!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the way it's worded or the way the data is given but I cannot understand the question.

Comment: lets assume I just want to get the integer value! not the time! and put them in a list. thats what I want to do in the first attempt

Comment: So you basically just want a list of all the "value"s? [50,100] (as in the first JSON example)?

Comment: yes, and then I can do the calculation for each value...

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense than the question.

Comment: one last question before I post my answer. In the case of the first example, do you want a full list like this? [[50,100],[200,300],[400,600]]?

Comment: Yes! full list or separate arrays are fine! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do. Replace `<JSON STRING HERE>` with the JSON String you were going to parse:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(<JSON STRING HERE>);

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i ++)
{
    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray valueArray = obj.getJSONArray("values");

    ArrayList<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    resultList.add(dataList);

    for(int j = 0; j < valueArray.length(); j ++)
    {
        JSONObject valueObject = valueArray.getJSONObject(j);
        Integer value = valueObject.getInt("value");
        dataList.add(value);
    }
}
```

The result is a list of lists of Integers called resultList. Good luck!

Remember, you have to wrap the whole thing in a try,catch as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get this error "Server failed to parse JSON" so lets get back few steps to what you did. until here: JSONArray valueArray = obj.getJSONArray("values"); everything is fine and I get three separate array with value and time but when I add the second loop it gets crazy

Comment: If you get "server failed to parse JSON" then your JSON is malformed. I already checked the code in my android emulator with the first string you gave me (the one at the top of your question) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question with the exact string you're passing to JSONArray arr

Comment: What I want to parse is a jsonArray with the exact format I sent: [{"values":[{"time":1434976493,"value":"50"},
{"time":1434976494,"value":"100"}],"counter":"counter1"}]. so instead of <JSON STRING HERE> I used the JsonArray. but anyway my problem is coming from this line: resultList.add(dataList); which gives me emoty list!!

Comment: It's supposed to be empty. You're adding the data after. When you add a list to a list you're actually passing a reference to that list. The way I did it is fine.

Comment: The problem was that I have dynamic values and sometimes they are NAN. so I got that error! but something else when I look into the code I do not think if we need list of the list!! it is expensive we can use simple list! now I am wondering how I can do it in a best way

Comment: I was doing a list of lists because your first example is an array of objects that contain arrays. I dont think you're being very clear on what your incoming data is like. Could you try clarifying in your question? Also, having a list of lists isn't really expensive. The outer list holds reference pointers (locations in memory) of the actual lists.

Comment: basically I just need two lists, we fill one of them with total  and in the other we put counter1 and then counter2 will be replaced in that list again.